# In widget using swiftui how to get current location?

Tags: swiftui, widget, core-location

How to fetch user  current location in widget ? I’m using swiftUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class WidgetLocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager? 
    private var handler: ((CLLocation) -> Void)?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            self.locationManager!.delegate = self
            if self.locationManager!.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
                self.locationManager!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchLocation(handler: @escaping (CLLocation) -> Void) {
        self.handler = handler
        self.locationManager!.requestLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        self.handler!(locations.last!)
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

call

```
var widgetLocationManager = WidgetLocationManager()

func getTimeline(for configuration: SelectPlaceIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> Void) {
    widgetLocationManager.fetchLocation(handler: { location in
        print(location)
        .......
    })
}
```

Comment: I didn’t help but made one step closer